# JSON parsing vs Regex based String parsing

Tags: java, json, parsing

I need to process a big JSON payload(~1MB) coming from an API, a portion of the JSON is something like this:

```
{
    "id": "013dd2a7-fec4-4cc5-b819-f3cf16a1f820",
    //more attributes
    "entry_mode": "LDE",
    "periods": [
        {
            "type": "quarter",
            "id": "fe96dc03-660c-423c-84cc-e6ae535edd2d",
            "number": 1,
            "sequence": 1,
            "scoring": {
                //more attribtues
            },
            "events": [
                {
                    "id": "e4426708-fadc-4cae-9adc-b7f170f5d607",
                    "clock": "12:00",
                    "updated": "2013-12-22T03:41:40+00:00",
                    "description": "J.J. Hickson vs. DeAndre Jordan (Blake Griffin gains possession)",
                    "event_type": "opentip",
                    "attribution": {
                        "name": "Clippers",
                        "market": "Los Angeles",
                        "id": "583ecdfb-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c",
                        "team_basket": "left"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "coord_x": 572,
                        "coord_y": 296
                    },
                    "possession": {
                        "name": "Clippers",
                        "market": "Los Angeles",
                        "id": "583ecdfb-fb46-11e1-82cb-f4ce4684ea4c"
                    }
                },
                //more events
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a nearly-realtime API that I need to process only the **events**, identify a set of event UUIDs, look for duplicates in the database and save new events.

I could use a JSONObject/JSONArray or use regex with string parsing to and fetch the events portion. Processing time is critical since this should be nearly-realtime and memory efficiency is important since there can be multiple payloads coming in at once.

Which one is more efficient for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper *streaming* JSON parser.  You know what you want to pull out of the stream, you know when you can quit parsing it, so read the stream in small, manageable chunks, and quit as soon as you know you are done.

Circa 2017, I'm not aware of any browser/native JSON streaming APIs, so you'll need to find a Javascript-based streaming library.  Fortunately, streaming is not a new concept, so there are a number of options already in existence:

1. http://oboejs.com/
2. https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream
3. https://github.com/creationix/jsonparse
4. https://github.com/dscape/clarinet
5. http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/demos/json/